# Save the PivotTable fields and filters in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2-advanced-app, pivottable.js

I am little bit confused with Pivot table in jquery. I am using **PivotTable.js**

first requirement

I render the JSON data using PivotTable.js. Now I need to save the row,cols and filters into a table when click a **save button** .

second requirement.

On select a value from a select box I want to repopulate the rows,cols and filters. and hide same values in

[image: Saving and retrieving requirement]

How can I do this any solutions or idea will appreciable

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link to an example to save configuration of PivotTable
[Save configuration](http://nicolas.kruchten.com/pivottable/examples/onrefresh.html). All you need to do is save resultant json in a server variable, do a post back and write to a table